# table's tbody shifts to right when printing in google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

I have a strange issue when I try to print a page with a table in google chrome (v 14).
When printing (by js function or even with cmd-P) it shifts the  element two cells right, leaving a white space before each row, but  and  remains in the same position.
This change affects even the printed page.
Then each time you try to print, the  is shifted two more cells right. and so long...

In firefox and IE this doesn't happen!
Any idea?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! I've found it!

there was a "float: left;" in the class of the first td of the tbody!
(it is a multi-developer-written stylesheet! :S )

Removing that, the print function works "normally"! :)

thanks anyway and sorry for the auto-response!